# why regex is not greedy here

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

The following code works as I expected. But I have one questions:

```
import re

names_email="Harry Rogers    harri@yahoo.com"

name_match=re.compile("([\w\s]*)(\s)([\w.]*@[\w.]*)")
name=re.search(name_match,names_email)
print (name.group(3))
print(name.group(1))

harri@yahoo.com
Harry Rogers
```

But why `([\w\s]*)` is not matching upto `Harry Rogers`     being greedy ? Why it is trying to match best possible for `([\w\s]*)(\s)`

Comment: Tried `print("#{}#".format(name.group(1)))`. It includes the spaces after `Rogers`.

Comment: I think you meant the regex to be

`name_match=re.compile("([\w\s]*)(\s)([\w\.]*@[\w\.]*)")`

Comment: It doesn't include four spaces after `Rogers` in first capturing group because a space character *must* be matched in another group. Although first group matches all 4 spaces, it backtracks to match a required space afterward.

Comment: The regex is primarily greedy until it stumbles on one character of its subsequent tokens, the placeholders after a greedy match is prioritary to be caught than the greedy regex itself.

Comment: you can tell in other way; imagine a rabbit with a lot of carrots ahead; you set the rabbit with greedy regex, the rabbit gets up to eat all of it, now if you set the rabbit to be greedy but skips white carrots, the rabbit would not eat the white ones, the greedy functionality holds its priority at that moment.

Answer (score 1):

> But why `([\w\s]*)` is not matching upto `Harry Rogers`      being greedy ?

It doesn't include four spaces after `Rogers` in first capturing group because a space character *must* be matched in another group after being satisfied with first pattern.

This means `[\w\s]*` [will match up to](https://regex101.com/r/7vG8Do/1) `@` character then backtracks to match a space character which is right after `h` in `harri`. Leaving first capturing group with `Harry Rogers`    (three space characters).

Answer (score 0):

It's because (\s) indicates it only matches one space if you want group(1) to only match the "Harry Rogers" without tailing space, the codes should looks like this:

```
import re

names_email = "Harry Rogers    harri@yahoo.com"

name_match = re.compile("([\w\s]*?)([\s]+)([\w.]*@[\w.]*)")
name = re.search(name_match, names_email)
print(name.groups())
```